# html table, select row by keypress

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js, keypress

I have simple table (using `knockout.js`), with feature to select row
http://jsfiddle.net/aDahT/447/

Now I want add next feature. Select row by keypress of first letter of the record's name.
e.g. if user press `b` then record `bbb` is selected.
if user press `h` then record `Ham` is selected.
How can I implement it?

Comment: I would look into the "event" binding for knockout: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/event-binding.html and go from there... what have you already tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, if you are forking a fiddle, run JSLint first. It will help you to make cleaner and more correct code. I came out with this: http://jsfiddle.net/a0viedo/Guf3u/.

Using `event.timeStamp` inside `keyPress()` handler you could determine if the user is typing or if its starting to type a new word.

Notice the (not so)little details:

- Extremely not performant for large setups of data.
- Case sensitive selector. You have to set the item value in some attribute of the html elements if you want to use a case unsensitive jquery selector.
- Hardcoded value at timeStamp difference (750 miliseconds). This hardcoded value has to reflect the threshold time between two keys during typing.

Hope it gives you any good idea.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution: http://jsfiddle.net/VEnsz/4/

I have data bound to the outer element:

```
<div style="width: 30em; max-height: 6em; overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: auto; border: 1px groove grey" data-bind="event: {keypress: selectByKeyPress }">
```

(You may pick another element in your application to attach the key press event to).

...and added the following function to your model:

```
self.selectByKeyPress = function(data, e) 
{

    var key = String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode).toLowerCase();
    var items = self.allItems();
    for (var j=0; j<items.length; j++) {
        if (items[j].toLowerCase().indexOf(key) == 0) {
            self.selectCurrent(items[j]); 
            return;
        }
    }      
}
```

Although you may need to refine this solution somewhat, I feel it is more in keeping with the 'knockout' way of doing things, so hopefully should provide you with a good basis to build your functionality on.